Why is the coefficient of $x^{\left(n-1\right)}$ in the expansion of $(x+1)\cdot(x+2)\cdot(x+3)\cdot...\cdot(x+n)$ is $\frac{n\left(n+1\right)}{2}$
So Today I had a lecture on binomial expansion and series, and our teacher just gave us a statement that the the coefficient of $x^{\left(n-1\right)}$ in the expansion of $(x+1)\cdot(x+2)\cdot(x+3)\cdot...\cdot(x+n)$ is  $\frac{n\left(n+1\right)}{2}$.
Later he justified his statement by just plugging the value for n=2,
$\left(x+1\right)\cdot\left(x+2\right)$ = $x^{2}+3x+2$ where the coefficient of x is equal to 3 and when me plug in the formula of the coefficient of x being  $\frac{n\left(n+1\right)}{2}$. We indeed get the coefficient osf x as 3.
Later he plugged in n=3,$\left(x+1\right)\cdot\left(x+2\right)\cdot\left(x+3\right)$ =$x^{3}+6x^{2}+11x+6$ where the coefficient of $x^{2}$ is 6 and from our formula we too get the coefficient of $x^{2}$ as 6. and then he moved on with his lecture without giving an rigorous explanation and just verified the statement by plugging in the value of n.
My question is Why is the coefficient of $x^{\left(n-1\right)}$ in the expansion of $\prod_{k=1}^{n}\left(x-k\right)$  is The sum of the first n natural number.
How can we find the coefficient for $x^{k}$?
what if instead of the expansion of $\prod_{k=1}^{n}\left(x-k\right)$ it is $\prod_{k=1}^{n}\left(2x-k\right)$ , what will be the coefficient of $x^{\left(n-1\right)}$?
what can be some intuitions to these kind of problems?
Thank you for taking your time to deal with my problem, I appreciate your help, and intuitions ,insights or new perspectives are accepted

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vieta%27s_formulas

You can expand the product $(x+1)(x+2)\dots (x+n)$. You get a sum $2^n$ terms. For example if $n=3$,
$$(x+1)(x+2)(x+3)=x^3 + 3x^2 +2x^2 + 6x +x^2 +3x +2x +6$$
Which of these term correspond to $x^{n-1}$? Well, you would need to choose $x$ in every factor $(x+k)$, except for exactly one. So you'll get $kx^{n-1}$ for every $k\in{1,\dots ,n}$. Summing, you get $x^{n-1}\sum k$. If there are minus signs, you will need to check parity. If there a $2$, then you will get $2^{n-1}\sum k$.

Think about it this way: how many ways are there to get $x^{n-1}$ from your product? Such a term can arise only if you're multiplying the number in one of the brackets and $x$ in the remaining brackets. But you can do this in $n$ ways, and each of the $n$ ways gives rise to a term like $kx^{n-1}$. Summing these you just get $\frac{n(n+1)}{2}$, which is the formula for the sum of the first $n$ natural numbers.

For a rigorous proof, one may use induction. As $ n = 1 $, it is trivial. Let us assume that
$$
(x + 1) \cdots (x + n) = x^n + \frac{1}{2} n(n + 1) x^{n - 1} + \cdots.
$$
Then
$$
\begin{align}
(x + 1) \cdots (x + n)(x + (n + 1))
= & \
\left( x^n + \frac{1}{2} n(n + 1) x^{n - 1} + \cdots \right)(x + (n + 1)) \\
= & \
x^{n + 1} + (n + 1) x^n + \frac{1}{2} n(n + 1) x^n + \cdots \\
= & \
x^{n + 1} + \frac{1}{2} \left( n^2 + 3n + 2 \right) x^n + \cdots \\
= & \
x^{n + 1} + \frac{1}{2} (n + 1)(n + 2) x^n + \cdots.
\end{align}
$$
Thus for all $ n \in \mathbb{N} $, the formula
$$
(x + 1) \cdots (x + n) = x^n + \frac{1}{2} n(n + 1) x^{n - 1} + \cdots.
$$
holds. Hence we complete the proof.
But I think, for this problem, intuition is more important than rigorous proof.
More generally, one has:
$$
(x + a_1) \cdots (x + a_n) = \sum_{k = 0}^{n} A_{k} x^k,
$$
in which
$$
A_{n - k} = \sum_{1 \le i_1 < \cdots < i_k \le n} \left( \prod_{\ell = 1}^{k} a_{i_\ell} \right).
$$
The proof is similar, hence I leave it for you as an exercise.

In the expansion of $\prod\limits_{k=1}^{n}\left(x+k\right)$,

the coefficient of $x^n$ is $1$ as you have to take the $x$ term from each of the $(x+k)$ terms
the coefficient of $x^{n-1}$ is $\sum\limits_{k=1}^{n} k =\frac{n(n+1)}2$ as for each $k$ you have to take the $k$ term and $x$ from the $n-1$ others
the coefficient of $x^0$ is $\prod\limits_{k=1}^{n}k=n!$ as you have to take all the $k$ terms
the coefficient of $x^j$ is an unsigned Stirling number of the first kind (listed at OEIS A132393).

Starting with $\prod\limits_{k=1}^{n}\left(x-k\right)$, you would get $1$, $-\frac{n(n+1)}2$, $(-1)^n n!$, and  signed Stirling numbers of the first kind (i.e. unsigned numbers times $(-1)^{n-j}$ listed at OEIS A048994) respectively.
Starting with $\prod\limits_{k=1}^{n}\left(2x-k\right)$, you would get $2^n$, $-2^{n-2}\frac{n(n+1)}2$, $(-1)^n n!$, and $2^j$ times signed Stirling numbers of the first kind respectively, as you have to multiply the result by $2^j$.

Combinatorial Approach:
So, you have $n$ factors, $(x+k)$ for $k=1,2,3,\cdots,n$.
If you expand the factorization $\prod_1^n (x+k)$, you get a polynomial, $\sum_0^n a_k x^k$.
The question is, more generally, how can we find the value of $a_k$?
Well, consider: when you expand the factorization, you are picking a term from every parentheses: an $x$, or one of the constants $k$. This forms one term in the final expression (which may group with like terms at the end).

Small Example: To show what I mean, suppose we expanded the factorization of
$$
(x+1)(x+2)(x+3)
$$
If you expand this entire thing manually, and do not group like terms, I can guarantee that one of them will be $x \cdot 2 \cdot x$, or $2x^2$. Slowly expand to see why.

This tells us something: when you choose $k$ $x$'s from the factorization, you will get $n-k$ other numbers to multiply together. The sum of all such numbers is $a_k$.

Small Example Continued: The ways to choose $2$ $x$'s from the factorization would be to pick, from the respective factors,

$1,x,x$
$x,2,x$
$x,x,3$

Sum up these numbers to get $6$. Since we chose two $x$'s, this is the coefficient of $x^2$. Note that, simplified, the expansion is in whole
$$
x^3 + 6 x^2 + 11 x + 6
$$


Additional Example: Nothing is special about the form of this polynomial beyond being a product of binomials (and the logic generalizes just fine even higher up). For instance, consider
$$
(4x+1)(x+1)(x-1)(7x+7)
$$
Let's find the coefficient of $x^2$. We pick two $x$'s from two factors, and two constants from others. This gives the possible combinations

$4x,x,-1,7$ (product $-28$)
$4x,1,x,7$ (product $28$)
$4x,1,-1,7x$ (product $-28$)
$1,x,x,7$ (product $7$)
$1,x,-1,7x$ (product $-7$)
$1,1,x,7x$ (product $7$)

We take the product of the numbers from each bullet point (listed in parentheticals) and then sum them up. The only caveat here is that we also need to account for the coefficient of $x$. (Perform the expansion manually: it becomes obvious why.) We account for this by multiplying it like the other numbers ($4x$ in the bullets is treated as $4$, etc.). We see that this gives $x^2$ to have coefficient $-21$. Note the full expansion is given by
$$
28 x^4 + 35 x^3 - 21 x^2 - 35 x - 7
$$

So, $a_{n-1}$ for your polynomial? You need to choose $n-1$ $x$'s, each with coefficient $1$. You get a (single) constant number at each stage, so there isn't even a need for multiplication. Do this for every possible choice of $n-1$ $x$'s, and sum the numbers you find.
Now realize that whenever you do this choosing of $n-1$ $x$'s, you're getting each of the constants $1,2,3,\cdots,n$ exactly once and once only. Hence,
$$
a_{n-1} = \sum_1^n k = \frac{n(n+1)}{2}
$$
as desired.
Hopefully it's clear from the second example how this logic can be generalized to other problems of your type.

Vieta's Formulas:
(Wikipedia article)
Hinted at in the comments, it is known that if a polynomial $\sum_0^n a_k x^k$ has roots $R := \{r_1,\cdots,r_n\}$, then
$$
\sum_{\text{$k$-member subsets $S$ of $R$}} \prod_{r_s \in S} r_s
= (-1)^k \frac{a_{n-k}}{a_n}
$$
For instance:

the sum of the roots ($1$-member subsets) is going to be $-a_{n-1}/a_n$: negative the ratio of the first two coefficients
the sum of products of pairs of roots ($2$-member subsets) is $a_{n-2}/a_n$

...and so on.
The polynomial $\prod_1^n (x+k)$ has roots $-1,-2,\cdots,-k$, clearly. Then you can use the $1$-subset formulation to solve for $a_{n-1}$ pretty easily (since clearly the polynomial is monic).

The coefficient of $x^{n-1}$ in the expansion after excluding exactly one factor from the given expansion is $1$. It means, the coefficient of $x^{n-1}$ in each of the expansions $(x+2)(x+3)(x+4)\cdots(x+n),~(x+1)(x+3)(x+4)\cdots(x+n),\ldots$ is $1$.
So, the coefficient of $x^{n-1}$ in the given expansion $(x+1)(x+2)(x+3)(x+4)\cdots(x+n)$ will be the sum $1+2+3+\ldots+n=\frac{n(n+1)}2$. Q.E.D.

It is convenient to use the coefficient of operator $[x^n]$ to denote the coefficient of $x^n$ of a series. This way we can write
\begin{align*}
{\color{blue}{[x^{n-1}]\prod_{k=1}^n(x+k)}}&=[x^{n-1}]x^{n-1}\sum_{q=1}^n(x+q)\tag{1}\\
&=[x^0]\sum_{q=1}^n(x+q)\tag{2}\\
&=\sum_{q=1}^nq\tag{3}\\
&\,\,\color{blue}{=\frac{1}{2}n(n+1)}
\end{align*}
Comment:

In (1) we select $n-1$ times $x$ from the factors, leaving a term $x+q, 1\leq q\leq n$.

In (2) we apply the rule $[x^p]x^qA(x)=[x^{p-q}]A(x)$.

In (3) we select the coefficient of $x^0$ which is the constant term $q, 1\leq q\leq n$ and apply the summation formula in the last step.


